# SQL Server 2008 - field to concatenate strings

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation

I'm running the following script, but the concatenated field is returning the incorrect values.

```
select customer_no, card_no, count(*) as no_trans,
stuff((select ',' + CAST(trans_id as varchar(20))
     from transactions a (nolock)
     where a.customer_no = b.customer_no and a.card_no = b.card_no
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS trans_ids
from transactions b (nolock)
where date>= '01 apr 2013'
and date < '30 apr 2013'
and trans_id in (select trans_id
          from product_items (nolock)
          where product_item in ('298029'))
group by customer_no, card_no
```

What I'm expecting to get is no. trans (count(*)) which have the product_item in it and return the list of trans_id as a concatenated field.

Eg.

```
customer_No            card_no        no_trans           trans_ids
1234                   12345          2                  1, 2
```

but what I'm getting is;

```
customer_No            card_no        no_trans           trans_ids
1234                   12345          2                  1, 2, 3, 5, 6
```

Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Sample Data

Transactions table

```
Customer_No         Card_No        Trans_ID
1234                12345          1
1234                12345          2
```

Product Items table

```
Trans_ID        Product_item
1               298029
2               298029
```

Comment: In the inner query also include Trans_Id in the where condition.

Comment: Hi, tried adding in "and a.tran_id = b.tran_id" but error message "transactions.trans_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." if I then add in group by trans_id I get a line for each...

Comment: @HL8 Can you give some Example Data to work with. I hope in helping to solve your Problem

Comment: Hi Luv, thank for your help in advance. I've updated with sample data.

Comment: `trans_id` condition should **also** be in `for xml` part of the query.

Comment: Hi Nikola, thanks for your reply by I've tried, see my above comments to Sivakumar...

Comment: With the sample data you have provided your query works just fine [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12db3/1). You need to update your the data to something that shows the issues you have.

Comment: You cannot simply join to outer row, you must repeat the condition in subquery because the way you were trying was selecting one row only in subquery (or *it would* if you could omit it in group by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your issue is that you need to filter against `product_items` in the `for xml` part of the query as well. You could do that by using a CTE where you query the rows you want from `transactions` and then use the CTE to concatenate `Trans_ID`.

Here is a SQL Fiddle with some sample data that shows what I believe is your issue and a query using a CTE that should do what you want.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a148/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table transactions
(
  Customer_No int,
  Card_No int,
  Trans_ID int
)

create table product_items
(
  Trans_ID int,
  Product_item int
)

insert into transactions values
(1234, 12345, 1),
(1234, 12345, 2),
(1234, 12345, 3),
(1234, 12345, 4),
(1234, 12345, 5)

insert into product_items values
(1, 298029),
(2, 298029),
(3, 298020),
(4, 298020),
(5, 298020)
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Your query
select customer_no, card_no, count(*) as no_trans,
stuff((select ',' + CAST(trans_id as varchar(20))
     from transactions a (nolock)
     where a.customer_no = b.customer_no and a.card_no = b.card_no
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS trans_ids
from transactions b (nolock)
where trans_id in (select trans_id
                   from product_items (nolock)
                   where product_item in ('298029'))
group by customer_no, card_no
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a148/2/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_NO | CARD_NO | NO_TRANS | TRANS_IDS |
------------------------------------------------
|        1234 |   12345 |        2 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- Rewritten to use a CTE
with C as
(
  select T.Customer_No, 
         T.Card_No,
         T.Trans_ID
  from transactions as T
  where T.Trans_ID in (select P.Trans_ID
                       from product_items as P
                       where P.Product_Item in ('298029'))
)
select C1.Customer_No,
       C1.Card_No,
       count(*) as No_Trans,
       stuff((select ',' + cast(C2.Trans_ID as varchar(20))
              from C as C2 
              where C1.Card_No = C2.Card_No and
                    C1.Customer_No = C2.Customer_No
              for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Trans_IDs
from C as C1
group by C1.Customer_No, 
         C1.Card_No
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a148/2/1)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_NO | CARD_NO | NO_TRANS | TRANS_IDS |
------------------------------------------------
|        1234 |   12345 |        2 |       1,2 |
```